# class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String

Tags: apache-spark

23/09/25 12:49:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 11)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String (org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData and org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

multiline_df = spark.read.schema(json_schema).option("multiline","true").json('/home/hadoop/Spark/json_single_read.json')

multiline_df.show()

Having this error for json file , Some data is read rightly but for the next records it gives this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema does not match the data in the file.  It's likely your schema would have indicated a String but actually has an array in the file itself.

Comment: Yes thanks , It was an issue for the defination of schema.

Comment: YW, please flag it as answered for others to be able to find it